# Changing DataGridCell foreground without affecting Selected and Focused base look

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created the following style for formating numerics:

```
       <Style x:Key="NumericCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource NegativesToRedConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="N2"/>
        </Style>
```

It achieves a look where text it's right-aligned, formatted as 'N2' and the foreground color of a negative number is red.

However, when a row in my `DataGrid` is selected the background turns blue and the foreground goes white, except for the column where I applied my custom style. There it keeps the red color. Red against blue is very hard on the eyes, so I'd like it to turn white when it's selected as the other un-styled cells.

I tried to solve this by adding a trigger to my style:

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

That does the trick, BUT! when the window is inactive the selected row background goes gray, but the foreground stays white, making for a weird look.

[image]

I looked for a way to read the focus status of my UserControl in which this DataGrid lives, but I had no luck. Oh WPF wizards, how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. Instead of always applying the style, I only apply it when the cell is not selected. It is basically just a reversed the trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="NumericCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="N2"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource NegativesToRedConverter}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Thanks to all that tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the colors of the InactiveSelection to make it look the same.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColorKey}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: No at a bad idea, but I think I found a better solution. Please see below.